# Why is it taking so long to upload photos to icloud from iPhone/iPad?

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, ipad, icloud, photo-stream

If I want to sell something online and create an ad on my Macbook, then snap a picture with my iPhone/iPad and both are connected to my home wifi, I kind of expect the photo to be uploaded instantly so I can use it on my Macbook. It's taking forever though. Could there be some kind of setting I have to change or some other problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it right now, why not plug the phone into the Mac & use Image Capture, in the Applications folder - which is the importer 'behind' Photos.app.

You can also set it to auto-launch any capable app, including itself, when a device is connected [or do nothing] & set exactly where your imports should be saved. You can also dictate whether it should auto-delete from the device afterwards, or alternatively you can manually delete any selected pictures.

[image]